# How to get quest-1 from github to load/clone into playground?

Tags: solana-program

I have imported Native- Hello Solana program from Github into playground and got it working. I am working towards minting a token on Solana devnet in playground. Listened to pirate bootcamp quest7 youTube tutorials several times. Unable to get quest-1 from Github to load/clone into playground.

When in playground I paste this url into import from Github window:
https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp.git
It enables the import button - when clicked it activates, then apparently fails and disables the import button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solana Playground supports importing projects from GitHub but the URL must be a Solana program workspace or a single Solana program.

You can import Anchor, Native or Seahorse workspaces from subfolders, e.g. from the repository you've shared: https://beta.solpg.io/https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp/tree/main/quest-2/tiny-adventure/program

An example for a Native program, [spl-memo](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/memo/program): https://beta.solpg.io/https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/memo/program